# Как обрезать картинку при помощи css?

Tags: html, css

[image: Нужно обрезать край у фона вот таким образом ,сзади фон тоже сделан картинкой .]

Нужно обрезать край у фона вот таким образом, сзади фон тоже сделан картинкой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например так, используя `clip-path`:

```css
.wrap  {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1459445364195-16475050193c?dpr=1&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1163&q=80&cs=tinysrgb) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 280px;
 background: url(http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/pics/pittsburgh.jpg) center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
     clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Леночка только маленькое НО не работает в FF IE и opera - только svg подходит в этом случае

Comment: @Geyan, тогда вырезать так фон, с этими углами. Это не стандартная задача для верстки.

Comment: да естественно , я нарисовал на svg но не могу сделать на 100% экрана , вывод сохранить как изображение , я не придираюсь - как и прежде любой ваш ответ плюсую , что на тостере что на ruSO

Comment: Большое спасибо , это то что мне надо . Век живи , век учись .